# Using Qt Tree Model to Store Data?

Tags: c++, qt

**Currently:**

I have created and populated a QTreeWidget with QTreeWidgetItems, and have set the text of the QTreeWidgetItems

**Problem: I have no idea how to actually utilize the QTreeWidgetItems for data storage**

Looking at: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum

```cpp
void QTreeWidgetItem::setData(int column, int role, const QVariant &value)
```

I see that I can use a Qt::ItemDataRole to specify the type of data stored, but none of the options in the enumeration pertain to actually storing raw data, only Qt properties.

**Questions:**

- How would I store actual data, such as doubles, within a
  WTreeWidgetItem?
- If I am not supposed to actually store data within the tree items, do I need to use an auxilary structure and use model indexes with internal pointers to link the 2 together?

**Info:**

- Qt5 (c++)
- MSVC 15 2017 + Qt Designer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the types supported by QVariant, and if it is not supported Qt points out the rules for new types to be supported, in the case of doubles it is supported so to save use the setData method to indicate and use an unused role by default like Qt::UserRole.

```cpp
float data = 5.0;
int column = 0
item->setData(column, Qt::UserRole, data);
```

And to get the data you must convert the QVariant obtained by the data() method of the QTreeWidgetItem:

```cpp
int column = 0
QVariant v = item->data(column, Qt::UserRole);
float value = v.toFloat(); // or v.value<float>();
```

Comment: Where does Qt point out how to support new type? I cannot find it in the namespace documentation.